# why does it say syntaxerror when i command for python version?

Tags: python-3.12

Ive just copied the location of the python file and pasted and thus the following syntax error is happening.

## the total program:

```
Python 3.12.2 (tags/v3.12.2:6abddd9, Feb  6 2024, 21:26:36) [MSC v.1937 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> C:\Users\Administrator\OneDrive\Desktop\Python 3.12 (64-bit).lnk
  File "<stdin>", line 1
    C:\Users\Administrator\OneDrive\Desktop\Python 3.12 (64-bit).lnk
       ^
SyntaxError: unexpected character after line continuation character
>>>
```

i expected it would show me my python version

Comment: At a Python REPL, you need to run Python code. The name of a .lnk file -- especially when not quoted as Python syntax -- is not Python code.

Comment: (also, the name of the .lnk file isn't the filename of the Python interpreter; it's a file for _a menu entry_ that refers to the interpreter, not the interpreter itself)

Comment: Moreover, you _already have_ the version info, before you do anything involving the lnk file at all -- `Python 3.12.2 (tags/v3.12.2:6abddd9, Feb  6 2024, 21:26:36) [MSC v.1937 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32` is all the identifying information about the build of Python you're running.